# Is this question wrong?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this question below wrong?

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be distinct positive integers that do not contain a $9$ in their decimal representations. Prove that $$\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_n} \leq 30.$$

The reason I think it is wrong is that this other question I solved gives a contradictory result because we can make $k$ arbitrarily large.

> Let $M$ be the set of all positive integers that do not contain the digit $9$ (base $10$). If $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ are arbitrary but distinct elements in $M$, prove that
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x_j} < 80 .$$

**Solution to second problem**:

There are exactly $8 \cdot 9^{k-1}$ $k$-digit numbers in $M$ since the first digit can be chosen in $8$ ways while any other position has $9$ possibilities. The least of them is $10^k$ and thus \begin{align*}\sum_{x_j < 10^k} \dfrac{1}{x_j} &= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{10^{i-1} \leq x_j \leq 10^i} \dfrac{1}{x_j} < \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{10^{i-1} \leq x_j \leq 10^i} \dfrac{1}{10^{i-1}} \\&=\sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{8 \cdot 9^{i-1}}{10^{i-1}} = 80 \left(1-\dfrac{9^k}{10^k} \right)<80.\end{align*}

Comment: I assume you’re looking at the $\left(1-\frac{9^k}{10^k}\right)$, and thinking that you can let $k \to \infty$ so that the sum $= 80$. But consider the *first* $<$ in that long equation.

Comment: The first one clearly implies the second one. The first problem probably requires sharper calculations.

Comment: We can get larger than $30$ is what I am saying.

Comment: @Lynn What do you mean?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Why do you think we can get larger than $30$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the $d$-digit integers with no $9$, there are $9^{d-1}$ starting with each digit $1$ to $8$, and the reciprocal of such an integer starting with $k$ is at most $1/(k \times 10^{d-1})$.  Thus the sum of the reciprocals is at most

$$ \sum_{k=1}^8 \sum_{d=1}^\infty \dfrac{9^{d-1}}{k \times 10^{d-1}} = \dfrac{761}{28} < 30$$

Comment: I don't see the difference between the first and second question.

Comment: It's the same question, just that more effort gets the bound from below $80$ to below $30$.  With still more effort, you could improve it still more.

Comment: @Puzzled417 The sum converges to $\approx 22.92067$. That’s less than $80$ (easy to prove) and also less than $30$ (tougher to prove).